# File-mapping and structure of file

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a form with fixed-size fields. When a user enters data, it gets put into a file. There have to be "next" and "prev" buttons to navigate through the records.

My idea is to define a space for the count number in the beginning of the file, define amount of space for every record, and just insert data (shifting the pointer every time). Is it a good practice?

```
LPCTSTR pBuf = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(fileMap, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 10240000);
int charSize = sizeof(TCHAR);
...
memcpy((PVOID)pBuf, "0", charSize); //Record's count number when creating the file
...
memcpy((PVOID)pBuf, teacher, 31 * charSize); //the teacher field has length of 30
pBuf = pBuf + 31 * charSize; //shift the pointer
memcpy((PVOID)pBuf, discipline, 21 * charSize);
//and so on for other fields
```

And another question. Every time a record inserted the number of records has to be updated. What is a correct way of shifting the pointer to the beginning? And the same question for shifting the pointer with "prev" and "next" buttons.

Thank you in advance.

**Update**
Here I try not to create a 10MB file, but instead to have it growing. I try to shift the view by `sizeof(record) * (*pCount) + sizeof(DWORD)`, but obviously I'm missing something...

```
HANDLE fileMap = CreateFileMapping(fileHandle, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(record) * ((*pCount) + 1) + sizeof(DWORD), NULL);
...
LPBYTE view = (LPBYTE)MapViewOfFile(fileMap, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, sizeof(record) * (*pCount) + sizeof(DWORD), sizeof(record)); 
...
record *pRecord = (record*)(view);
```

Comment: Do you think your design is ok if you use memcpy in c++? Why not using obejcts? Entries & lists and a representation in the file. What I can see from your snipped looks ugly!

Comment: I know it's ugly, that's why I asked the question, I'm just a beginner in WinApi. Thank you for the suggestion of using entries and lists, I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple views into a file at the same time.  So you can create one view just for the count field and keep writing new values to the same pointer each time, then create another view for reading/writing records to the file.

You already know how to use pointer arithmetic to move a pointer around (though you are not doing ot correctly in your code example).  To make things easier, since your fields are fixed, you should define a `struct` that has all of the fields of a record, and then read/write entire `struct` values at one time. That will also help you manage your pointer shifts, as you would simply add/subtract `sizeof(the struct type)` number of bytes to your view pointer.

With that said, I would not suggest creating a 10MB view of the file.  For one thing, it requires the file to be at least 10MB in size to begin with, even if it does not have 10MB worth of data in it, thus wasting disk space.  You might want to re-think your mapping strategy so the file starts with just the initial counter and grows in size as new records are written.  You would simply re-map the file when it grows, but you can still maintain a view that slides around the file's content by creating views at different offsets as needed (don't forget to take page boundaries onto account). Don't keep the entire file in a single view at all times since you are only accessing small sections at a time. It may be more convenient but it wastes more memory.

Try something like this:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct record
{
    TCHAR teacher[31];
    TCHAR discipline[21];
    //and so on for other fields
};
#pragma pack(pop)

...

SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo
HANDLE fileMap;
LPDWORD countView;
LPBYTE currentView;
record* recordView;

...

GetSystemInfo(&sysinfo);

fileMap = CreateFileMapping(fileHandle, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(DWORD), NULL);
countView = (LPDWORD) MapViewOfFile(fileMap, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, sizeof(DWORD));
currentView = NULL;
recordView = NULL;

*countView = 0;

...

DWORD dwCount = *countView;

DWORD recordStart = sizeof(DWORD) + (dwCount * sizeof(record));
DWORD viewStart = (recordStart / sysinfo.dwAllocationGranularity) * sysinfo.dwAllocationGranularity;
DWORD viewSize = sizeof(record) + (recordStart % sysinfo.dwAllocationGranularity);
viewSize = (viewSize + (sysinfo.dwPageSize-1)) & ~(sysinfo.dwPageSize-1);
DWORD viewOffset = (recordStart - viewStart);

if (countView)
    UnmapViewOfFile(countView);
if (currentView)
    UnmapViewOfFile(currentView);
if (fileMap)
    CloseHandle(fileMap);

fileMap = CreateFileMapping(fileHandle, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, recordStart + sizeof(record), NULL);

countView = (LPDWORD) MapViewOfFile(fileMap, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, sizeof(DWORD));
currentView = (LPBYTE) MapViewOfFile(fileMap, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, viewStart, viewSize); 
recordView = (record*) &currentView[viewOffset];

lstrcpyn(recordView->teacher, teacher, 31);
lstrcpyn(recordView->discipline, discipline, 21);
//and so on for other fields

++(*countView);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Remy. I started to implement what you said. I don't create a 10MB file, but enlarge it by sizeof(record) + sizeof(DWORD) every time. And I try to create a view for onlyt one next record every time. Here is my code:

`HANDLE fileMap = CreateFileMapping(fileHandle, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(record) * ((*pCount) + 1) + sizeof(DWORD), NULL);

LPBYTE view = (LPBYTE)MapViewOfFile(fileMap, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, sizeof(record) * (*pCount) + sizeof(DWORD), sizeof(record));

record *pRecord = (record*)(view);`

It doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: You are not taking page boundaries into account. I warned you about that. A view must start at an even multiple of the system granularity, you cannot start it at an arbitrary offset. This is clearly stated in the `MapViewOfFile()` documentation. What I do in my mapping code is take the *desired* file offset and round it down to the nearest page boundary, create the view, and calculate the offset between the *desired* view start and the *actual* view start so that I can skip those bytes then accessing the view's data.

Comment: Also, when you create a new file mapping, such as when the file size changes, you have to unmap and create a new `pCount` view as well, since you have to close the previous file mapping that was backing it.